# erro when submiting spark application

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing, apache-spark-standalone

i am trying to submit a very simple application,it consists to create two rdds from one input large file (about 500 GO), subtract the header (first line), zip them with indexes, map them to key-value with a small modification then save them as a text file

i was able to see on spark web UI the progress of jobs, the last 2 jobs was failed due to this error please tell me what is its reason and how to solve it

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4897 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4897.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 4914, localhost): java.io.IOException: Aucun espace disponible sur le périphérique
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
>       at org.apache.spark.storage.TimeTrackingOutputStream.write(TimeTrackingOutputStream.java:58)
>       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
>       at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.finish(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:243)
>       at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.close(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:175)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.DummySerializerInstance$1.close(DummySerializerInstance.java:65)
>       at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter$$anonfun$close$2.apply$mcV$sp(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1296)
>       at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.close(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:107)
>       at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.commitAndClose(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:132)
>       at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.writeSortedFile(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:188)
>       at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.closeAndGetSpills(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:410)
>       at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.closeAndWriteOutput(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:204)
>       at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:164)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:

PS; there is a french sentence :

> Aucun espace disponible sur le périphérique :it means there is no available space  on this device,

well i think it is the reason but i didn't understand which device  and how to solve it

Comment: can you check spark scratch space disk size / spark worker directory size. I guess thats is what running out of space

Comment: how can i check it?

Comment: @Rohith Yeravothula

Comment: are you using any cluster manager like Mesos or Yarn or using simple spark  standalone ??

Comment: In case of standalone master -> It needs to be set in spark-defaults. if not set spark will assume local directory (where spark folder is present ) as worker directory. In such case please check that particular disk space.

Comment: yes i am using standalone, i am sorry for asking this but iam new to spark and linux, so how can i check the size of this directory, and ho to configure it in spark-defaults?

Comment: and do u mean that the worker use this space for processing or for saving outputs? please forgive me because i'mstill learning

Comment: firstly you don't have to apologize, use command "df -h" to see all disks and look out for the disk containing the spark folder. check if that disk is running low on space while running the application.